# Use one of the Apply Functions instead of a nested for loop in R

Tags: r, apply

As an R newbie I think its time to take the step away from for loops and into the apply functions. I am struggling with this bit of code, and am wondering if anyone can help.

I have a function:

```
earth.dist <- function (long1, lat1, long2, lat2)
{


rad <- pi/180
  a1 <- lat1 * rad
  a2 <- long1 * rad
  b1 <- lat2 * rad
  b2 <- long2 * rad
  dlon <- b2 - a2
  dlat <- b1 - a1
  a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
  c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
  R <- 6378.145
  d <- R * c
  return(d)
}
```

Now I have two different data sets, one with a list of predetermined large cities and their long/lat coordinates and one with random locations in America with their long/lat coordinates. The for loop that I have written basically calculates the difference between each long/lat coordinates of the random locations to the long/lat coordinates of the predetermined large city and places the random location in the State which the closest city is located in. Each city in the predetermined list has a State next to it which is inserted in a new column in the random cities spreadsheet.

Is there a way I can do this loop using apply? This loop actually does do the trick but it is so long and bulky and I know that an apply function can do a better job.

Here is the loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(randomlocations)){
  vec<-vector()
  for(j in 1:nrow(predeterminedcities)){
    a<-earth.dist(randomlocations$long[i],randomlocations$lat[i], predeterminedcities$long[j], predeterminedcities$lat[j])
    vec[[j]]<-a
  }
  ind<- as.numeric(which.min(vec))
  randomlocations$state[i]<-as.character(predeterminedcities$STATE[ind])
  print(i)
  }
```

Comment: It appears that `earth.dist` will accept vectors of latitudes and longitudes. If this is true, feed it the whole vector of the predetermined cities in one go: `a<-earth.dist(randomlocations$long[i],randomlocations$lat[i], predeterminedcities$long, predeterminedcities$lat)`.

Comment: Thanks @Imo! Do you know how I can know which row, or predetermined city, the smallest distance is using this technique?

Comment: The output of the vector (if it does work on a vector), will be ordered by the predetermined cities, so you can use those positions to pull out that info. maybe take a look at `which.min` if that is unfamiliar.

Answer (score 1):

Since your function is already vectorized, you can use `outer` to compute a distance matrix by passing through indices into the data frames. Pop that result through `max.col` to find the index of the smallest distance, then use that to find the state name:

```
#fake test data
randomlocations <- data.frame(lon=runif(100, -80,-70), lat=runif(100, 45,75))
predeterminedcities <- head(randomlocations, 50)
predeterminedcities$STATE <- state.name

randomlocations$state <- predeterminedcities[
  max.col( -
    outer(1:nrow(randomlocations), 1:nrow(predeterminedcities), 
      function(i,j) earth.dist(randomlocations$lon[i], randomlocations$lat[i], 
                             predeterminedcities$lon[j], predeterminedcities$lat[j])
    )
  ), "STATE"]
```

This would easily fit on one line if the variable names were shorter.